# Socket closed error when I close Ganymed Session and Connection after issuing command

Tags: java, python, ssh

I have an Android app built with Java where I send SSH commands to a Python package on-demand to a server whenever an action warrants it. To explain the context, I open a Ganymed connection to a server, then open a session and from that session start an interactive shell so that I can import my custom Python class and call a function from it feeding in data whenever an update occurs on the app. I can't issue individual commands as it would take to long too open a Python instance, import, open a ZMQ socket on the server, etc, every time.

Here's the code to open the shell:

```
session = connection.openSession();
session.requestDumbPTY();
session.startShell();
os = session.getStdin();
os.write("python\n".getBytes());
os.write("from package.data_receiver import DataReceiver\n".getBytes());
os.write("DR=DataReceiver()\n".getBytes());
os.write("DR.open_socket()\n".getBytes()); //opens the zmq socket on server
```

`os` being an `OutputStream` global variable in the Java class that my other method can call `write()` on to run commands on the Python class `DR`.

However the issue arrises when I want to close the connection/session/outputstream.

```
os.write("DR.close_socket()\n".getBytes()); //closes the zmq socket on server
os.write("exit()\n".getBytes()); //exits python
os.write("exit\n".getBytes()); //exits the shell

os.close();
session.close();
connection.close();
```

When this code is run, I get `W/TransportManager: Receive thread: error in receiveLoop: Socket closed` and the last line: `DR.close_socket()` does not get ran. I'm not totally sure if I even need to close any or all of these, as I can close the OutputStream and the last command will still execute on the remote server. Any tips would be appreciated. Thanks!

Edit: Yeah, just checked and if I don't call `connection.close()`, then the previous connections still remain active to the server, but if I call even just that, I get that error and the last command doesn't run.

Comment: Which line throws the exception?

Comment: @user207421 Right, the closing connection code is in a separate method in the same class as the above code, so that it can access the global class variables os, session and connection. The first block is in a method called getSession() and the second closeConnection(), so the second can be called whenever the connection must be closed. The error occurs whenever session.close() is called, or connection.close() is called but not os.close()

Comment: Well I suggest that `os.close()` closes the session.

Comment: I need it to terminate the connection to the server, however it will remain open if I just run `os.close()`. The final command executes perfectly with or without closing the OutputStream, however it leaves the connection open. Closing the connection throws the error and the last command is not executed, but it does close the connection successfully. It's almost like it's running before my `close_socket` line. Is writing to the OutputStream done in the background?

Comment: Ahh, I get it now. The OutputStream just writes the commands into the interactive shell without waiting, and the remote server takes these commands in order, immediately executing each one in succession. However without checking the output on the app's side, it cannot know when it is finished. I totally assumed it waited until each command is written with `os.write`, however now I am checking whether a response code is returned from the server and wait for that! Works perfectly now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I figured out a solution to this specific problem: For whatever reason, if I remove the line to exit the shell, and keep just the line that closes the connection, the final command is still executed and the connection successfully closes as well. The error I got before still occurs when I have `connection.close()`, but everything seems to be working as expected.

I removed:

```
os.write("exit\n".getBytes());
```

And I kept:

```
connection.close();
```

Comment: Following up on this: The actual issue is that I wasn't waiting for the last command to run before I closed the SSH connection. I set it up so the Python server replied by printing a string of text and waited until the Android app received that specific output, then I closed the connection. Works perfectly now!